# Getting this json into the correct format chain flatten groupby

Tags: json, format, underscore.js

I have been trying for ages to make this work and still have no answer to something that I thought would be quite straightforward, trying to group and count types, I have this:

```
[
  {
    "type": "TypeOne",
    "day": "2016-07-07"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeOne",
    "day": "2016-07-07"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-07"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-08"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-08"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-08"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeFour",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeFour",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  }
]
```

I need to be able to count the occurrences of Type by the date and turn it into this structure:

```
[
  {
     "date":"2016-07-07"
    ,"TypeOne":2
    ,"TypeTwo":1
    ,"count":3
  },
  {
     "date":"2016-07-08"
    ,"TypeTwo":2
    ,"TypeThree":1
    ,"count":3
  },
  {
     "date":"2016-07-09"
    ,"TypeTwo":1
    ,"TypeThree":3
    ,"TypeFour":2
    ,"count":6
  }
]
```

I've been trying to make it work with underscore, chain, groupBy and map, just not able to make it happen. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the structure and aggregate the values:

```js
var dates = [
  {
    "type": "TypeOne",
    "day": "2016-07-07"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeOne",
    "day": "2016-07-07"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-07"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-08"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-08"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-08"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeFour",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeTwo",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeThree",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  },
  {
    "type": "TypeFour",
    "day": "2016-07-09"
  }
];

var result = [];

dates.forEach(function(d) {
  var date = result.find(function(da) { return da.date === d.day; });
  if (!date) {
    date = { date: d.day, count: 0 };
    result.push(date);
  }
  
  date.count++;
  if(!date[d.type]) {
    date[d.type] = 1;
  } else {
    date[d.type]++;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, thanks so much Tholle, this was killing me! One more question, could I also add a "count": total field to the groups to show the total of all items in each group?

Comment: @Nigel Sure. Edited the question and the answer. Consider accepting the answer if it answered your question.